# Customize Laravel FormRequest autorize method validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

Laravel allows us to authorize, or not, a FormRequest to be processed via the [authorize method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#authorizing-form-requests). If the request isn't authorized, it will throw a `\Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException` exception, with a message:

> This action is unauthorized.

Is there somehow to customize this message?

See that I want to customize the message itself. [Customizing the error messages of attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-messages) I know it is possible!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To change the message you can add the following to your `FormRequest` class.

```
protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    throw new AuthorizationException('Your new message goes here.');
}
```

Don't forget to add the following to the class as well:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was looking for. thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to `use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;`

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to customise the message authourization exceptional message then use throw new exception in authorization controller itself in else part